# ASP.NET MVC Routing issue with action parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm fairly new to MVC4, and I'm having a problem getting a custom route off the ground.

I don't want to explain what my end goal is, since it's fairly complicated, but right now I simply want this url:

```
/Home/GetView/contacts/pv
```

to hit the GetView action of my home controller, and pass it parameters of "contacts" and "pv" for its `module` and `name` parameters

```
public PartialViewResult GetView(string module, string name)
```

Unfortunately when I set a breakpoint, both of these parameters are `null`.

Here's the route I'm trying to use

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PartialView",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{module}/{name}"
);
```

and I've also tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PartialView",
    url: "Home/GetView/{module}/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetView" }
);
```

According to the docs I'm reading that should work fine, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you putting your new route before the default route?

Comment: Odd.  I copied your second MapRoute and your GetView method into a fresh MVC4 app and it works fine.

Comment: @Jason - I think this may be a caching issue - the address is coming from a link in my htm file, and I think it's getting cached such that the wrong address is getting sent over the wire :(

Comment: Indeed it is.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: CTRL+F5 FTW! (15 chars).

Comment: CTRL+F5 is the "standard" browser keystroke to force the browser to clear its cache and request the page again from the server.  You should still use F5 in Visual Studio to start debugging.